# Three products for a single price when checkout

Tags: magento2

I am trying to give an offer to my website users where they can choose three 
T-shirts and pay only ₹999 irrespective of the cost of each t-shirt.
I have tried to achieve this through cart price rules but i was not able to achieve what i expected. Can anyone help me out with this???
the following is my website link.
https://habit69.com

Comment: Can you specify detail about your requirement? What you actual want?

Comment: For example in t-shirts category if a user chooses to buy 3 products or 3 quantity in single product i will charge them only ₹999(including or excluding shipping charges). Is this helpful???

Comment: What about if customer by 5 Product and 6 Product?

Comment: if it is 6 products the price will be ₹999 * 2 , if it is 5 products only for three products the price will be ₹999 and for rest of the two it will be the actual price

Comment: you can achive by using Event observer, you need to change product price there.

Comment: could you guide me please because i am not so good in magento 2

Comment: I post answer, which help you. please check that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Magento 2 provide functionlity to set custom product price before product add to cart. For that you need to use "checkout_cart_save_before" event.

Create file `[vendor][Extension]\etc\frontend\event.xml` and specify this code for your event.

```
<event name="checkout_cart_save_before">
    <observer name="[your_event_name]" instance="[vendor]\[Extension]\Observer\AddtocartbeforeObserver" shared="false" />
</event>
```

Now create a file in `[vendor][Extension]\Observer\AddtocartbeforeObserver.php`

```
namespace [vendor]\[Extension]\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class AddtocartbeforeObserver implements ObserverInterface
{
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        // DO YOUR LOGIC TO SET ITEM PRICE

        $item = $observer->getEvent()->getData('quote_item');         
        $item = ($item->getParentItem() ? $item->getParentItem() : $item );

        $price = YOUR_PRICE; //SET PRICE ACCORDING TO YOUR LOGIC

        $item->setCustomPrice($price);
        $item->setOriginalCustomPrice($price);
        $item->getProduct()->setIsSuperMode(true);
    }
}
```

**NOTE :** In above observer, you need to put the logic for how many already item in cart, and according to that you can change price of old item as well as newly added item.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. Let me try this. Thank you so much.

Comment: If My answer help you, please accept it, So it will help other in community as well.

Comment: Hi Dhiran, It seems to be complicated for me to customize the code as you explained. Is there any other option through which we can achieve this? Please ..

Comment: I know this way, So I suggested this way to you, according to your requirement.